# ingredients adjuster for cookies

Tags: java, jgrasp

While running the bellow code, I am getting the following error message:

> No main method, JavaFX Applications, applets, or MIDlets found in the
>   file

I'm confused on why I'm getting the message though if I have defined `main()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CookieRecipe 
 { 

   public static void main(String [] args) 
    {


       //Declare Variables
      double cupsofSugarPer48Cookies = 1.5;
      double cupsofButterPer48Cookies = 1;
      double cupsofFlourPer48Cookies = 2.75;
      int regularBatchofCookies = 48;
      int userNumberofCookies;

      double expectedCupsofSugar;
      double expectedCupsofButter;
      double expectedCupsofFlour;

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.println("Number of Cookies you need" );
      userNumberofCookies = scanner.nextInt();

      expectedCupsofSugar = ( userNumberofCookies / regularBatchofCookies ) * cupsofSugarPer48Cookies;
      expectedCupsofButter = ( userNumberofCookies / regularBatchofCookies ) * cupsofButterPer48Cookies;
      expectedCupsofFlour = ( userNumberofCookies / regularBatchofCookies ) * cupsofFlourPer48Cookies;

       //Display Information
      System.out.println( "For" + userNumberofCookies + "Number cookies you will need" + expectedCupsofSugar + "cups of Sugar," + 
                         expectedCupsofButter + "cups of Butter" + expectedCupsofFlour + "cups of Flour.");

   }

}
```

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: @Mike, you can flag as "Unclear what you are asking"

Comment: Please update your post with your question.

Comment: I am getting the "No main method, JavaFX Applications, applets, or MIDlets found in the file" when I try to run this program can you tell me what I'm doing wrong @drum

Comment: @Vega those are all valid `String[] args`, `String [] args`, `String args[]` or `String args []`. Mostly because java uses character like `,` or `;` to know when a declaration statement ends.

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild it. Note that you are using a specific IDE that might be the cause of your problem. Can you give us more details about the build + run procedure you are using